Trying to boot ubuntu from usb for first time but bootmgr missing error appears
When I try to boot into Ubuntu from my USB for the first time, I get an error that says:
bootmgr is missing

My computer is a HP that came stock with Windows Vista.
What can I do that isn't that nerdy?

Have you checked the checksum of the installation file you downloaded? If not, do so (procedure depends upon the version, you'll find it easily). You'll probably find the checksum is wrong.

Would reinstalling help here?

What computer is it (brand name and model)? Which version of Ubuntu are you trying to run? How did you install it into the USB drive (which tool/method did you use)? Please help us help you (edit your original question to add your answers to our questions).

Download a new USB installer ISO and write it to your system with something like Balena Etcher. The error you indicated suggests that your USB may have a bad installer image on it.
